# Can you tie notes across multiple bars?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

I have just started to learn music theory and I was trying to write a melody. I was using ties to join the notes, but can anyone tell me if the thing that I have done in this image is possible or not?

[image: Image Of Problem]

Comment: The only thing that I see that could potentially be an issue (short of the whole note as mentioned in alephzero's answer) would be whether or not the instrument you're writing for is capable of sustaining a note for that long.  This isn't a particularly long note, depending on tempo, but a longer set of notes tied in this manner may not work as desired.  For instance, the voice is limited by breath and technique.  Anything that doesn't have a lot of sustain would also have an issue with this as well.

Answer (score 9):

You can tie any number of notes together, so that is OK.

But the filled-in black note head with no stem is wrong. If you were trying to draw a whole-note, it shouldn't be filled in.

[image]

Comment: Yeah that was a whole note, my bad.